# ColdFusion 10 component intermittently losing mapping

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Having an issue where I will be using a component, instantiated like this:

```
<cfset xmlLib = CreateObject("component", "myLIB.mycfc")>
```

and it will all of a sudden start throwing errors that it cannot find the component.
'Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface myLIB.mycfc'.  I am really at a loss as to why it will suddenly lose these mappings.

Comment: do you have myLib mapping in cfadmin ?

Comment: yepp...it will be working fine and then it will suddenly start producing that error

Comment: Can you experiment with an app mapping in your Application.cfc?   this.mappings['myLIB'] = 'path/to/myLIB';  Also, you could try catching the error and dumping out a directory list of /myLib to see where CF is pointing the mapping to (or if it even exists)

Comment: Well what is weird is that there are several other mappings within the app, all going to that same path (myLIB) that work everytime, without issue.  Actually, where I am finding this error, its one of 5 components used and it is the only one that is failing.

Comment: Is there some sort of load balancing, cluster, or something where it's running on multiple instances of JRun or Tomcat? The key here is that it's intermittent, so either it's running in multiple places (servers or instances), or there's something about the code where this runs _from_, such as the CFC instantiation running from within an IF or CASE statement... can you give us more details?

Comment: No load balancer, clustered environment, or anything like that.  Just ColdFusion with apache.  I have the cfc instantiation with a few others at the top of the cfc and they all work fine.

Comment: I saw on Twitter you gave a little more info (http://imgur.com/nywBOKy). Is reversePublish.cfc instantiated in an Application, Session, or other shared scope?

Comment: reversePublish.cfc is a rest file, so ColdFusion handles that file based on where it lives and how its mapped (the rest) in the admin.